# GCP - Uploading data to Firestore from CSV

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I have a CSV file I am using to upload data to our Firestore database.

The file has 16,000 records.

I am using the Google Cloud Platform CLI to upload the data via a node.js script.

The import works until it has imported approximately 3,000 records and then crashes.

The CLI displays the following error:

> Error: 16 UNAUTHENTICATED: Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential.

Comment: Are you using transactions? how many records per operation are you using? (Ej. 10.000 reads). Have you tried refreshing the token after a number of operations?

Comment: Not using transactions, not sure how to refresh the token

Comment: Can you add some code sample, I could try to reproduce it? Maybe you should think of catching this error and  try reconnect....? Are you doing it from local machine?

Comment: I am doing in in the Goggle Cloud Platform cli. If I can catch the error, how do I reconnect?

Answer (score 2):

Catch the error and reconnect calling the Firebase object again:

```
const {Firestore} = require('@google-cloud/firestore');

// Create a new client
const firestore = new Firestore();

try {
  //my program with the error...
}
catch (e) {

   //request a new client:
   const firestore = new Firestore();
   //keep going...
}
```

Comment: if I catch the error within the loop and create a new firestore will that not mean the add failed so I will need to repeat the failed add operation?

Comment: Which operation are you using? Update?